# Installing elementary OS on Thinkpad X1C7 - has anyone done this? & did you have wifi problems?

Tags: system-installation, wifi, networking, thinkpad

I'm a noob and apologies if this a v basic question. I'm trying to install this on my new Thinkpad X1 C7, but when trying latest version on live, everything seems to be working okay except wifi is not detected. Anyone else tried installing this on a similar machine and it worked out of the box? Or have advice on how to resolve wifi issue? Also, wondering if you did install this on a Thinkpad X1C7, did you do any tweaks to make the audio sound as awesome, and also on heating and battery optimisation?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to share internet connection from phone via usb and still wait notification from AppCenter. I have some problem on my PC and when i connected in internet i got notification about driver for wi-fi device.
[image]